# Sorting ObservableCollection based on date value in the item class

Tags: c#, silverlight, sorting, observablecollection

This question may be look like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11191074/1196411), but the implementation is different. i am using that example only for my new implementation

I have following ObservableCollection in my class, I am binding data to my listbox using that Collection in my Windows phone 7 application

```
public ObservableCollection<CustomClass> myList = new ObservableCollection<CustomClass>();
```

I tried the following way but sorting not happening properly

**My Class**

```
public class CustomClass : IComparable<CustomClass>
{
 public string Id { get; set; }        
 public string Name { get; set; }        
 public string CreatedDate get{ get; set; }

 public int CompareTo(CustomClass  other)
    {
        var compareDate1 = DateTime.Parse(CreatedDate);
        var compareDate2 = DateTime.Parse(other.CreatedDate);
        return compareDate2.CompareTo(compareDate1);

    }
 }
```

**SUB Class**

```
public class ComparingObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
 where T : IComparable<T>
{

protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
{
    if (!Items.Contains<T>(item))
        {
            try
            {
                var bigger = Items.First<T>(F => F.CompareTo(item) > 0);
                index = Items.IndexOf(bigger);
            }
            catch
            {
                index = Items.Count;
            }
            finally
            {
                base.InsertItem(index, item);
            }
        }
  }
}
```

Problem is not with logic, it is with input dates, i am querying next 15days createddates without checking the year
below code is working but need to handle the days of dec/jan months

**UPDATE**
My Custom Class

```
public class CustomClass : IComparable<CustomClass>
{
public string Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public DateTime Created { get; set; }

private string _CreatedDate;
public string CreatedDate
{
    private get
    {
        return _CreatedDate;
    }
    set
    {
        Created = DateTime.Parse(value);
        _CreatedDate = value;
    }
}

public CustomClass(string id, string name, string created)
{
    Id = id;
    Name = name;
    CreatedDate = created;
}

public int CompareTo(CustomClass other)
{
    return CreateDate.Date.DayOfYear.CompareTo(other.CreateDate.Date.DayOfYear);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to have this class sorted by itself (CreatedDate)

```
public class CustomClass : IComparable<CustomClass>
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    private string _CreatedDate;
    public string CreatedDate
    {
        private get
        {
            return _CreatedDate;
        }
        set
        {
            Created = DateTime.Parse(value);
            _CreatedDate = value;
        }
    }

    public CustomClass(string id, string name, string created)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        CreatedDate = created;
    }

    public int CompareTo(CustomClass other)
    {
        return Created.CompareTo(other.Created);
    }
}

public class ComparingObservableCollection<T> :  ObservableCollection<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    // this function presumes that list is allways sorted and index is not used at all
    protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
    {
        if (!Items.Contains<T>(item))
        {
            try
            {
                var bigger = Items.First<T>(F => F.CompareTo(item) > 0);
                index = Items.IndexOf(bigger);
            }
            catch 
            {
                index = Items.Count;
            }
            finally
            {
                base.InsertItem(index, item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried it and mentioned in my question also its not sorting properly

Comment: its not sorting according to the date, the order of the items in the collection is not correct

Comment: maybe because you use date as string ?
instead of as a DateTime

Comment: i convert it into DateTime before comparing `var compareDate1 = DateTime.Parse(CreatedDate);`

Comment: Why not store it as a DateTime, all the time ? you could have a property, or constructor that accepted datetime as string, and converted then. Storing date as string is usually quite messy.

Comment: your `ComparingObservableCollection<T>` class just working like normal `ObservableCollection` its not sorting, just adding elements at the end of the collection

Comment: i'll get a string from user, at that time also i have to parse it and set to date

Comment: i am getting Sequence contains no matching element `InvalidOperationException`

Comment: `var bigger = Items.First<T>(F => F.CompareTo(item) > 0);` this line giving above exception

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14133/discussion-between-raghuveer-guthikonda-and-stig)